# Open new window from quick launch in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  //add an entry to the _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames array
  //so that our function will run on the pageLoad event
  _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("rewriteLinks");

  function rewriteLinks() {
    //create an array to store all the anchor elements in the page
    var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

    //loop through the array
    for (var x=0; x<anchors.length; x++) {
      //does this anchor element contain #openinnewwindow?
      if (anchors[x].outerHTML.indexOf('#openinnewwindow')>0) {
        //store the HTML for this anchor element
        oldText = anchors[x].outerHTML;

        //rewrite the URL to remove our test text and add a target instead
        newText = oldText.replace(/#openinnewwindow/,'" target="_blank');

        //write the HTML back to the browser
        anchors[x].outerHTML = newText;
      }
    }
  }

</script>
```

I have this code I put in the seattle.master file before  Then in quick launch when I edit links I put #openinnewwindow after the website address. On "try link" this opens the website right. My problem is when I save it. And click the link it does not open in a new window. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: +1 for comments in the code. Did you check the resulting HTML? Does the script run and its job properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized for this code to work that I needed Publishing enabled.